# Hyperledger explorer in docker-compose is not working with the Hyperledger blockchain

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-explorer

I am trying to get hyperledger explorer to work with docker-compose, hyperledger blockchain explorer did not connect to the hyperledger blockchain network. It says "Failed to connect client peer, please check the configuration and peer status". However I followed all instructions I could find to get it to connect.

The Hyperledger explorer starts up and I can access it at http://localhost:8090/ but it does not connect to the blockchain.

Here is the github project where it is not working.

https://github.com/contractpendev/hyperledger-basic-network

Blockchain Explorer comes from here.

https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer

---

Finally I think my question is not a good question as no-one else is likely to have this problem anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a comment asking for more info, but since I don´t have enough rep yet to comment, I guess I'll try an answer instead!

All of the following assume that Blockchain Explorer is run in a docker container, using the supplied deploy_explorer.sh script. All examples below should work with the first-network sample network from fabric-samples, assuming that fabric-samples has been cloned to ~/fabric/fabric-samples.

Firstly, are there any more detailed errors reported in either the docker logs (docker logs {container-name}) or the log file in the container (/opt/logs/app/app.log)?

Have you done the following?

- **Confirm that you are using the correct Blockchain Explorer version for your fabric version** - e.g. explorer 3.7 for fabric 1.2.
- **Clean-up any existing Blockchain Explorer installation** - if you had a previous version installed, you should remove it first using the supplied deployment script, i.e.

  `cd ~/fabric/blockchain-explorer`
  `./deploy_explorer.sh --clean`
- **Clone and/or check-out the correct release of the blockchain explorer repository** - e.g.

  `cd ~/fabric`
  `git clone https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer.git`
  `cd blockchain-explorer`
  `git checkout release-3.7`
- **Create a folder under "blockchain-explorer/examples" for your network** - e.g.

  `cd ~/fabric/blockchain-explorer/examples`
  `mkdir first-network`
- **Create a config.json file for your network** (in the folder created above). You can take a copy of the sample file from ~/fabric/blockchain-explorer/examples/net1/config.json and modify it accordingly.
- **Create a symbolic link to crypto-config** (in the same folder), e.g.

  `cd ~/fabric/blockchain-explorer/examples/first-network`
  `ln -fs ~/fabric/fabric-samples/crypto-config crypto`
- **Deploy Blockchain Explorer** - specifying the name of the folder containing your config, and the name of your docker network, e.g.

  `cd ~/fabric/blockchain-explorer`
  `./deploy_explorer.sh first-network net_byfn`

You should now be able to connect to explorer at http://localhost:8080/. If the page still doesn't load, check the docker logs for any errors (docker logs blockchain-explorer).

See https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer/blob/master/README.md for more details (replacing "master" with the label for release you are using, e.g. "release-3.7").

**Also, please note that the port exposed when using `deploy_explorer.sh` has changed between release-3.7 and release-3.8 from 8080 to 8090. This one caught me out for quite some time!**