# How to start the explorer v3.7

Tags: hyperledger-explorer

I want to run the hyperledger explorer to display my fabric network，but failed.Has
anyone know why?Very pleased to hear from your answer.
Here is my fabric network:
[fabric network status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cq7fA.png)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cq7fA.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/x40Ya.png**strong text**

And my crypto-config absolute path is/root/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/e2e_cli
this is my explorer config.json file:

```
{


"network-configs": {
    "network-1": {
      "version": "1.0",
      "clients": {
        "client-1": {
          "tlsEnable": true,
          "organization": "Org1MSP",
          "channel": "mychannel",
          "credentialStore": {
            "path": "./tmp/credentialStore_Org1/credential",
            "cryptoStore": {
              "path": "./tmp/credentialStore_Org1/crypto"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "channels": {
        "mychannel": {
          "peers": {
            "peer0.org1.example.com": {}
          },
          "connection": {
            "timeout": {
              "peer": {
                "endorser": "6000",
                "eventHub": "6000",
                "eventReg": "6000"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "organizations": {
        "Org1MSP": {
          "mspid": "Org1MSP",
          "fullpath": false,
          "adminPrivateKey": {
            "path":
              "fabric-path/fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore"
          },
          "signedCert": {
            "path":
              "fabric-path/fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts"
          }
        },
        "Org2MSP": {
          "mspid": "Org2MSP",
          "adminPrivateKey": {
            "path":
              "fabric-path/fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp/keystore"
          }
        },
        "OrdererMSP": {
          "mspid": "OrdererMSP",
          "adminPrivateKey": {
            "path":
              "fabric-path/fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/users/Admin@example.com/msp/keystore"
          }
        }
      },
      "peers": {
        "peer0.org1.example.com": {
          "tlsCACerts": {
            "path":
              "fabric-path/fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt"
          },
          "url": "grpcs://localhost:7051",
          "eventUrl": "grpcs://localhost:7053",
          "grpcOptions": {
            "ssl-target-name-override": "peer0.org1.example.com"
          }
        },
        "peer1.org1.example.com": {
          "url": "grpcs://localhost:8051"
        },
        "peer0.org2.example.com": {
          "url": "grpcs://localhost:9051"
        },
        "peer1.org2.example.com": {
          "url": "grpcs://localhost:10051"
        }
      },
      "orderers": {
        "orderer.example.com": {
          "url": "grpcs://localhost:7050"
        }
      }
    },
    "network-2": {}
  },
  "configtxgenToolPath": "fabric-path/fabric-samples/bin",
  "license": "Apache-2.0"
}
```

error message is ：
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cq7fA.png)

could anyone can help me how to edit the config.json file or tell me the error point

Comment: I upload the wrong adminPrivateKey signedCert tlsCACerts path .In my config.json they have been changed to /root/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/e2e_cli/crypto-config/...

Answer (score 0):

Please see my answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53129074/hyperledger-explorer-in-docker-compose-is-not-working-with-the-hyperledger-block) question on running Blockchain Explorer. Following these instructions and using the config.json file below should get you running with the standard first-network example.

```
{
  "network-configs": {
    "network-1": {
      "version": "1.0",
      "clients": {
        "client-1": {
          "tlsEnable": true,
          "organization": "Org1MSP",
          "channel": "mychannel",
          "credentialStore": {
            "path": "./tmp/credentialStore_Org1/credential",
            "cryptoStore": {
              "path": "./tmp/credentialStore_Org1/crypto"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "channels": {
        "mychannel": {
          "peers": {
            "peer0.org1.example.com": {}
          },
          "connection": {
            "timeout": {
              "peer": {
                "endorser": "6000",
                "eventHub": "6000",
                "eventReg": "6000"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "organizations": {
        "Org1MSP": {
          "mspid": "Org1MSP",
          "fullpath": false,
          "adminPrivateKey": {
            "path":
              "/tmp/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore"
          },
          "signedCert": {
            "path":
              "/tmp/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts"
          }
        },
        "Org2MSP": {
          "mspid": "Org2MSP",
          "adminPrivateKey": {
            "path":
              "/tmp/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp/keystore"
          }
        },
        "OrdererMSP": {
          "mspid": "OrdererMSP",
          "adminPrivateKey": {
            "path":
              "/tmp/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/users/Admin@example.com/msp/keystore"
          }
        }
      },
      "peers": {
        "peer0.org1.example.com": {
          "tlsCACerts": {
            "path":
              "/tmp/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt"
          },
          "url": "grpcs://peer0.org1.example.com:7051",
          "eventUrl": "grpcs://peer0.org1.example.com:7053",
          "grpcOptions": {
            "ssl-target-name-override": "peer0.org1.example.com"
          }
        },
        "peer1.org1.example.com": {
          "tlsCACerts": {
            "path":
              "/tmp/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer1.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt"
          },
          "url": "grpcs://peer1.org1.example.com:7051",
          "eventUrl": "grpcs://peer1.org1.example.com:7053",
          "grpcOptions": {
            "ssl-target-name-override": "peer1.org1.example.com"
          }
        },
        "peer0.org2.example.com": {
          "tlsCACerts": {
            "path":
              "/tmp/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt"
          },
          "url": "grpcs://peer0.org2.example.com:7051",
          "eventUrl": "grpcs://peer0.org2.example.com:7053",
          "grpcOptions": {
            "ssl-target-name-override": "peer0.org2.example.com"
          }
        },
        "peer1.org2.example.com": {
          "tlsCACerts": {
            "path":
              "/tmp/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer1.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt"
          },
          "url": "grpcs://peer1.org2.example.com:7051",
          "eventUrl": "grpcs://peer1.org2.example.com:7053",
          "grpcOptions": {
            "ssl-target-name-override": "peer1.org2.example.com"
          }
        }
      },
      "orderers": {
        "orderer.example.com": {
          "url": "grpcs://orderer.example.com:7050"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "configtxgenToolPath": "/home/fabric-path/workspace/fabric-samples/bin",
  "license": "Apache-2.0"
}
```